# How to delay an animation in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

So basically I have this code:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)" style="color:#000000">
    <div style="width:300px; height:250px; z-index:4; border:2px solid #6aa5fa; background-color:#2d2d2d; position:fixed;" class="click-layer" id="clickLayer">
        <div class="resized-splitflap">Dublin</div>



    </div>
</a>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.splitflap.js"></script>
<script>
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var ratio = 0.5;
            $('.resized-splitflap')
                    .splitFlap({
                        charWidth:  25 * ratio,
                        charHeight: 50 * ratio,
                        imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
                    });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

And at the moment what this code does is that it flips the characters as soon as the page loads but I want it to do it after few seconds lets say 10 so how would I go on to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)?

Comment: Use **[`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)**.

Comment: @blgt what is that? Im new to Jquery so wouldnt know about it. Could you help me out?

Comment: @TahirAhmed where would I put that function into the code I have?

Comment: @ViratKohli: `$('.resized-splitflap').delay(1000).splitFlap({ ... });`

Comment: @TahirAhmed Whether `.delay()` could be used or not depends on if the plugin is actually using/adding to the jQuery animation queue, as the method only manipulates queued animations.

Comment: @TahirAhmed that didn't work but thank you for your help :)

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a reasonable question to me! (Have upvoted it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `window.setTimeout()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var ratio = 0.5;
        $('.resized-splitflap').splitFlap({
            charWidth:  25 * ratio,
            charHeight: 50 * ratio,
            imageSize:  (1250 * ratio) + 'px ' + (50 * ratio) + 'px'
        });
        }, 10 * 1000);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked! However I can just see plain text is there a way to remove this and only show when the animation gets played?

Comment: Sure, just use CSS to hide the wrapper div eg `display:none` and then jquery to `show()` it.